# Unable to scroll in mobile with attempt at CSS sticky footer

Tags: css, iphone, footer, sticky-footer

I am working on developing [this site](https://philandersonphotography.com/about) and am at a loss for why, when I try to generate a sticky footer for scrolling pages such as the linked one, it will not scroll on a mobile device (tested on an iPhone in Safari and DuckDuckGo). My goal is to add a sticky footer such that the footer is at the bottom of the page always (not at the bottom of the viewport always).

I have tried to change the positioning of the footer using `fixed`, `absolute`, or `relative`. For `fixed`, it will scroll but the footer stays at the bottom of where the viewport initially was. The latter two both result in being unable to scroll the screen in mobile. However, Chrome Developer Tools using a mobile device (namely an iphone) will produce the desired behavior). I have tried various tutorials including [this one on sticky footers](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/).

I currently have my footer formatted as such,

```
.site-footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background-color: white;
}
```

With a responsive setting for mobile that modifies a couple parameters,

```
.site-footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I realize this is not a full minimum reproducible example but I'm struggling to generate something that is portable enough to share here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code and you will have sticky ;)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .site-footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: This yields a footer that is positioned at the bottom of the viewport on page load but it stays at that position/height on the page such that it scrolls up (see that page updated with your suggestions). This is not my understanding of a sticky footer. it also doesn't solve the inability to scroll as far as i can see. Thanks